# Modify existing excel Connection Name in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, external, oledbconnection

I need to update the Connection Name of an excel workbook's sql connection.  This is my attempt.  I have been able to modify the Connection String and Command Text by doing a standard replace.

```
Sub ConnectionString_modify()

Dim i As Long
Dim cnt As Long
Dim modtext As String
Dim modrange As String

'Grab nummber of workbook connections
cnt = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count

For i = 1 To cnt

    'Changes to Connection string --This works
    modtext = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(i).OLEDBConnection.Connection
    modtext = VBA.Replace(modtext, "_FY2013", "_FY2014")
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(i).OLEDBConnection.Connection = modtext

    'Changes Connection Name
    modname = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(i).Name
    modname = VBA.Replace(modname, "_FY2013", "_FY2014")
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(i).Name = modname 
 Next i

End sub
```

Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem exactly?  Do you get an error? If Yes, on which line and what's the exact message?

Comment: This code will run without error but the name of the connection string does not change.  What does seem to happen is that the i-th connection name changes to a different one in the set.  So if i check before connections.items(i) = Connection10 after I try my rename code its connections.items(i) = Connection7. It seems like I need another method to rename.  Currently this code just reorders the Connection names.

Comment: Try putting the connection objects into a collection and looping through the collection instead.  Sometimes modifying objects in a loop like you're doing can cause the objects to re-order during the process.  Or try setting a reference to each connection and working with that reference instead of referring to .Items(i)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Sub ConnectionString_modify()

Dim i As Long
Dim cnt As Long
Dim modtext As String
Dim modrange As String
Dim conn

'Grab nummber of workbook connections
cnt = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count

For i = cnt To 1 Step -1

    Set conn = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(i)

    modtext = conn.OLEDBConnection.Connection
    modtext = VBA.Replace(modtext, "_FY2013", "_FY2014")
    conn.OLEDBConnection.Connection = modtext

    conn.Name = VBA.Replace(conn.Name, "_FY2013", "_FY2014")

Next i

End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Excel dynamicly sorts the Connection.Item() array.  So my modifications were sending the updated Names to the bottom of the array.
Before:   FY2013Conn1, FY2013Conn2, FY2013Conn3, FY2013Conn4 
After:    FY2014Conn2, FY2014Conn3, FY2014Conn4, FY2014Conn1

This was hard to see because I was dealing with 50+ connections. What I found to be effective was instead of trying to iterate through the entire set, only modify the first item in the array.

```
'Connection Count
cnt = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count 

While cnt > 0
   'Always modify the first Item 
   Set conn = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(1)

   'Mod code makes changes to Command Text
    modtext = conn.OLEDBConnection.Connection
    modtext = VBA.Replace(modtext, "_FY2013", "_FY2014")
    conn.OLEDBConnection.Connection = modtext

    'Changes Connection Name
    conn.Name = VBA.Replace(conn.Name, "_FY2013", "_FY2014")

    'Iterate through the cnt
     cnt = cnt - 1
  Wend
```

Thanks for everyone's help.