# Store Connection Names in Excel VBA - Add to connection text

Tags: vba, excel

I have got a workbook containing several worksheets. 
Parameters are entered on one sheet, and I am on the way to creating a macro which takes these parameters, adds them to the connection string and then updates each table on each sheet.

I have got it working for one connection, but I am struggling to find a way of storing each connection name and then and looping through each connection adding the variables.

Here is the code I have so far, some of it is commented out..which is how I managed to solve the problem for one connection.  Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

```
Sub Update()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Parameters")

    Dim startdate As Date
    Dim enddate As Date

    startdate = Range("week_start_date").Value
    enddate = Range("week_end_date").Value
    MsgBox "Values are " & startdate & " and " & enddate

    Dim nm As ActiveWorkbook.Connections.name

    Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
        For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        .CommandText = "exec dbo.'" & name & "', @start = '" & startdate & "', @end = '" & enddate & "'  "


    'With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ps_STS_Op_Summary_Approvals").OLEDBConnection
        '.CommandText = "exec dbo.ps_STS_Op_Summary_Approvals @start = '" & startdate & "', @end = '" & enddate & "'"

    End With
    'ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ps_STS_Op_Summary_Approvals").Refresh
    For Each wSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each qt In wSht.QueryTables
    qt.Refresh
    Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify existing excel Connection Name in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837971/modify-existing-excel-connection-name-in-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the number of connections stored in the workbook and then loop through them using the .item(x) property of ActiveWorkbook.Connections:

```
cnt = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count

For i = cnt To 1 Step -1

    Set conn = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(i)
    'Do stuff to conn

Next i
```

[Also refer to this question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837971/modify-existing-excel-connection-name-in-vba)

Comment: Thanks very much, that's a big help